# Implementing custom two factor authentication, why does GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync() returned a null User?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
namespace weblogint2.Areas.Identity.Data
{
    public partial class AuthSignInManager<TUser> : SignInManager<ApplicationUser> where TUser : class
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly weblogint2Context _db;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
        IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> _claimsFactory;
     
        public AuthSignInManager(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
            IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
            ILogger<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>> logger,
            weblogint2Context dbContext,
            IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes,
            IUserConfirmation<ApplicationUser> confirmation)
                : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes, confirmation)
        {
            _userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contextAccessor));
            _db = dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
            _claimsFactory = claimsFactory;
        }

       public override async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
        {
            // WHAT AM I MISSING HERE?

            if (userName.ToLower() == "admin@xx.tt" && password.ToLower() == "111111111@")
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(SignInResult.TwoFactorRequired);
            }
            else
            if (userName.ToLower() == "admin1@xx.tt" && password.ToLower() == "111111111@")
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Success);
            }
            else
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Failed);
            }
        }
      
        public override async Task<SignInResult> TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync(string code, bool isPersistent, bool rememberClient)
        {
            var results = Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Failed);
            string GeneratedCode = "124578";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
                return await Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Failed);
            else if(string.Equals(code,GeneratedCode))
            {

                return await Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Success);
            }
            else
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(SignInResult.Failed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**At *Login* Page**

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Input.Email)
    };
}
if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
{
    // control is commine here 
    var currentUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);

    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });//, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe}) ;
}
```

**At *Loginwith2f* page**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(bool rememberMe, string returnUrl = null)
{
    // Ensure the user has gone through the username & password screen first
    var user = await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();

    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unable to load two-factor authentication user.");

       // NULL HAPPENS HERE
    }

    ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    RememberMe = rememberMe;

    return Page();
}
```

**`ApplicationUser` `class`**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    
    [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar(100)")]
    public string FirstName { get; set;     }

    [PersonalData]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string LastName { get; set;    }

    [PersonalData]
    [Column(TypeName = "bit")]
    public bool IsSystemAdministrator { get; set; }

}
```

**At `Startup.cs`**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>, AuthSignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
}
```

've implemented custom `AuthSignInManager` class when page is redirected to `LoginWith2fa`. I get `null` at `await _signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();`

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR**

You're overwriting `SignInManager<T>` however the functionality you are trying to replace are interfaces themselves. You can replaced the user validation (via [IUserValidator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuservalidator-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1)) and claims creation (via [IClaimsTransformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation?view=aspnetcore-3.1)) logic with their specific interfaces allowing the `SignInManager<T>` to function as normal.

**Explanation**

There are a few issues with your code, here are two of the most relevant:

1. Your `AuthSignInManager<TUser>` never actually signs the user in. Typically the act of signing a user in done via one of the [AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.signinasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1) (example: `HttpContext.SignInAsync(...)`)
2. The code at your Login page is creating Claims but never associating them to the user. This is typically handled within [IClaimsTransformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Based on what it seems from your code you are trying to validate user credentials (username and password), append additional claims when credentials are valid, then conditionally continue with the two step verification process.

ASP.NET Core Identity offers ability to easily implement custom code for specifically these tasks. Here are the interfaces needed to implement:

1. [IUserValidator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuservalidator-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1) - Remove your `PasswordSignInAsync()` implementation from `AuthSignInManager` and instead implement a custom instance of [IUserValidator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuservalidator-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to validate user credentials.
2. [IClaimsTransformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation?view=aspnetcore-3.1) - Remove the code to create claims in your Login page and instead place it within an implementation of [IClaimsTransformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation?view=aspnetcore-3.1).
3. Register your custom implementations of [IUserValidator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuservalidator-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [IClaimsTransformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.iclaimstransformation?view=aspnetcore-3.1) within the `ConfigureServices()` within *Startup.cs*. Also remove the registration of your `AuthSignInManager<ApplicationUser>` from `ConfigureServices()`.

Comment: i do not understand. do i remove AuthSignInManager or i implement with IUserValidator. and which class should implement IClaimsTransformation methods? 
Secondly which class should implement IClaimsTransformation.